# How to get Specific Cell Value from CSV With Respect To Row And Column Value using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, anaconda, data-science

sample data:

```
user,hotel_name,city,review

adam,hotel1,chennai,"Wow, what charm! As a Travel Agent.

john,hotel2,pune,Great location for sporting events.

mike,hotel3,mumbai,Its the best of the best.

george,hotel4,delhi,Ok hotel in a bad location.
```

Hello all,

I would like to print the `review` given by mike from csv file. I am new to python can some one help me?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your csv is in a file a called `data.csv` and you're running the script in the same directory.

Then you would do something like:

```
import pandas as pd              # bring in pandas

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')     # load data
print(df[df['user'] == 'mike'])  # add a mask for mike and print row
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['user'] == 'mike','review']`

Answer (score 0):

Two ways, first with Python:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    for line in reader:
        if line[0] == 'mike':
            print line[3]
            break
```

Now with Bash:

```
grep "mike" file.csv | cut -d, -f4

Its the best of the best.
```

Comment: In case if there is another row having user mike it is printing only the first review

Comment: remove the `break` if you have more than one line where the user is `'mike'`

Comment: perfect output  that I expected :)